# swipe gesture with mouse on desktop, like Photoswipe, but animate a div

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, swipe, photoswipe

I'm searching for a script like Photoswipe that works on desktop on mouse events, simulating swipe gestures.
Photoswipe without thumbnails is perfect - only I want to animate not only images but a whole div!

Comment: This needs more attention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first good-looking result was a jQuery plugin called [jQuery mouseSwipe](http://torontographic.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/jquery-mouseswipe/).
But this script only moves around a parent div which contains the items visually moved around.
If that is not enough, you should consider writing something for yourself.

Listen to `mousedown` and `mouseup` events and check the distance from the startpoint to the endpoint. If it is higher than a threshold you defined, let's say 100 Pixel, go to the next or previous element, based on the direction of the movement.

If you want it to be animated, you should also listen to the `mousemove` event and move the element around.

Comment: thx, great! Yes, it works with html-input in the divs.
It's only the examples that use only images!